# How to merge two lists of string in Python

Tags: python, string, list, merge

I have two lists of string:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = ['d', 'e', 'f']
```

I should result:

```
['ad', 'be', 'cf']
```

What is the most pythonic way to do this ?

Answer (score 7):

Probably with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
c = [''.join(item) for item in zip(a,b)]
```

You can also put multiple sublists into one large iterable and use the `*` operator to unpack it, passing each sublist as a separate argument to `zip`:

```
big_list = (a,b)
c = [''.join(item) for item in zip(*biglist)]
```

You can even use the `*` operator with `zip` to go in the other direction:

```
>>> list(zip(*c))
[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e', 'f')]
```

Comment: This one also works with an arbitrary number of lists, by using `zip(*list_of_lists)`.

Comment: Yes. Also keep in mind that you can use the `*` operator to un`zip` things: `list(zip(*c))` produces `[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e', 'f')]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

```
>>> a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> b = ['d', 'e', 'f']

>>> [ai+bi for ai,bi in zip(a,b)]

['ad', 'be', 'cf']
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
[c + d for c,d in zip(a,b)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
zip(a,b)
[('a', 'd'), ('b', 'e'), ('c', 'f')]

[x+y for x,y in zip(a,b)]
['ad', 'be', 'cf']
```

You can also use enumerate with list comprehension:

```
[j+b[i] for i,j in enumerate(a)]
['ad', 'be', 'cf']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lambda` together with `map`:

```
map(lambda x,y:x+y,a,b)
```

Or add `zip` to manage more than 2 lists:

```
map(lambda x:''.join(x), zip(a,b,c))
```

For python < 3 I would prefer the former option or replace `zip()` for `izip()`, for python 3 the change is not necessary (`zip` already return an iterator).